# dashing - Get value from a widget over api

Tags: ruby, dashing

A newbie here. I have found out how I could post values to different widgets over the REST api.
I would like to know how I can get values from a widget. E.g. 'current' value from a number widget.
If I do a Get on the http://dashingURL/dashboard_name then I only get the html from the ERB files but not the current values the widgets hold.

Please could you advise - thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot get the data from REST API, it is done as server side event. may someone contributes js client to handle this. Try to use chrome developer to debug the event data

Answer (score 1):

The dashing data is pushed via [server side event](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), you cannot use REST API to get it from server.

But you can listen to the server event to catch the data, which is url ends with `events`

You can try `curl` command to experience it.

```
curl  http://dashingURL/events

data: {"current":19,"last":80,"id":"valuation","updatedAt":1471517030}

data: {"current":33631,"last":188824,"id":"karma","updatedAt":1471517030}
```

Check your widget ID like `karma` to get latest data then